# GitHub pull requests: is there a quick way to get to the contributor's branch?

Tags: github

When reviewing a pull request, it is sometimes useful to have a look at what the contributor's branch looks like. I find it frustrating that the below label (highlighted in yellow) is **not** a hyperlink that takes me there:

[image]

I wonder why that is? I wouldn't even mind if it was a dead link (for merged pull requests it could happen that the contributor's branch doesn't exist anymore for example.)

What would be the alternative (outside of fetching their repo locally... etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refined Github, a browser extension, adds this and much more:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github

It was actually the first feature added to the addon:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/1